# Azure IoT hub SDK supports Windows CE 4.X?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am developing for pocket pc 2003 device in Visual Studio 2008, and wonder if I can use the Azure IoT hub sdk library there !

Comment: [Azure IoT hub SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks) support a variety of languages and platforms. You can check for your platform and language, try to use and post what problem you encounter.

Comment: Hi Rita! Thanks for reply! Pocket pc 2003 released more than 10 years ago and it's operating system is Windows CE 4.X which is also very old.. Even in this case, is it also possible to use? Actually I tried to search it more than few hours but I failed :(

Comment: That's why I suggest to have a try by yourself instead of searching on the network. It will be faster to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

The official C SDK for IoT Hub doesn't support CE 4.x out of the box. It is certainly possible to port it to CE 4.x but that might not be simple. The main thing that the C SDK depends on and that could be challenging is an SSL stack.
There is a [porting guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/doc/porting_guide.md) that explains how the SDK is architected and how one can port to new platforms.